# Get rid of the borders on an <input> box

Tags: html, css

I have the below HTML. I would like to make this so that it is just a white space without borders. I tried removing borders with CSS like this: `#search-box {border: none;}` but that did not work. Any thoughts?

Here is the HTML that it is in:

```
<div id="topNav">

<span class="topNavLink" id="headingTitle" >Word 4 Word</span>

<span id="topNav1two">
<a href="#" id="home" class="topNavLink">Home</a>
<a href="#" id="new" class="topNavLink">New Test</a>
</span>
<span>
<input type="search" size="35" id="searchInput"><!--this is the search box-->
<input type="button" value="Search" id="searchBttn">
</span>

<span>
<a id="feedback" target="_blank" class="topNavLink">Help</a>

<a href="#" id="settings" class="topNavLink">Settings</a>

</span>


</div>
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
/*Deals with the top nav*/

#topNav {
          padding-top: 10px;
          padding-bottom: 10px;
          background: black;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100%;
        }

.topNavLink {
              text-decoration: none;
              color: orange;
              padding-left: 10px;
              padding-right: 10px; 
            }

#headingTitle {
                font-size: 1.3em;
              }

/* ends top nav */

/* Deals with the search bar */

#searchBttn {
              height: 25px;
            }

#searchInput{ 
              border: none; 
              background: black;
            }

/* ends the search bar */
```

Comment: if that is your real code your top span tag is not closed. This will create a ton of bugs.

Comment: [I see no border](http://jsfiddle.net/kYPVR/). Please fix your problem so that we can see your problem.

Comment: @Thorn007 hmm... good point, I just fixed that and it did not make a difference.

Comment: @BalusC what do you mean? There is a thin white border. I want it to be completely black so you can't even tell the `input` is there.

Comment: This is apparently specific to certain Chrome versions.

Comment: @BalusC thats weird I wonder why.

Comment: Why is your type=search? Are you using html5? Changing it to type=text may help you debug. Also, you may want to post all of your code or a link to your site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest you try setting:

`#search-box { border: 1px solid transparent; }`

Failing that, try forcing the issue with this:

`#search-box { border: 0; }`

Comment: that does not totally work, it does the same type of thing as `border: none;`. I want the border to be non-existent. See the code I just added above. With the black background on the `body` and the `input` it still has a border.

Comment: Are you sure that IE6 is not inheriting a border style from further up the CSS document or from any supporting CSS files?

Comment: This is definitely related to your input type. If you change "search" to "text" here `<input type="search"/>` it works easily. I'm not sure what to do to fix this for the html5 type `search` but at least now we know where to look...

Comment: ah.. thanks, forgot it was a search. I probably shouldn't use that type anyway for compatibility's sake.

Comment: See also http://bitesizebugs.wordpress.com/2009/08/17/border-none-not-working-on-text-input-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 3):

[That works](http://jsbin.com/oyudu4) for me (Chrome9 on Win7). What browser are you using? Maybe post more of your code?

Comment: hmm... thats weird. See the relevant HTML and CSS I just added above

Answer (score 0):

border: none can be used with input[type="text"], like so:

```
input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
}
```